# Timeline jquery is not working in wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am working on Wordpress Avenue theme.I need to include a Timeline jQuery in my project.I have 4 main files of the jQuery:

```
 1. styletime.css
 2. modernizrtime.js 
 3. http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js
 4. main.js
```

I need to include these files in the same order otherwise it create conflicts and doesn't work.
How to include these in wordpress theme?

I have tried this but it is not working.no js is working

```
function script_timeline1() {
wp_enqueue_script('custom_script1', get_template_directory_uri() .'/modernizrtime.js', array ( 'jquery' ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','script_timeline1');


function custom_style_sheet() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-styling', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/styletime.css' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_style_sheet');

function theme_js() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );

function main(){
wp_enqueue_script('main_func', get_template_directory_uri() . '/main.js', array ( 'jquery' ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','main');
```

Comment: Add jQuery at the top in the functions.php file

Comment: Oh, so you need the syntax to add in functions.php file?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to write a function for including cdn for js(file no.3)

Comment: please review: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

Comment: yes i need the syntax for cdn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two folder into your theme folder one for css file and other one for js file **(put you css and js file in that folder. i.e. your_theme_folder/css/styletime.css, your_theme_folder/js/modernizrtime.js, your_theme_folder/js/main.js)**. Put below code into your theme's functions.php file.

```
function theme_load_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_style('styletime', get_template_directory_uri () . '/css/styletime.css', false, 1.0, 'all');
   wp_enqueue_script('modernizrtime', get_template_directory_uri () . '/js/modernizrtime.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
   wp_enqueue_script('main', get_template_directory_uri () . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_load_scripts' );
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: i changed get_template_directory_uri () to get_stylesheet_directory_uri () for scripts and it worked perfect for me.working fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: Just an example

There should be a functions.php in you theme folder

```
function theme_js() {
     wp_register_script( 'html5_shiv', 'http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js', '', '', false );

     wp_enqueue_script( 'owl', get_asset('owl.carousel.js','js'), array('jquery'), '', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );
```

Or even this :

```
function theme_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'styleTime', 'styletime.css', false );    
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );
```

Comment: i changed get_template_directory_uri () to get_stylesheet_directory_uri () for scripts and it worked perfect for me.working fine now :)